# How to install the latest Scrapyd package?

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, scrapy, apt-get, scrapyd

I notice that the latest stable version of `scrapy` was released last week(2013-08-09). After updating scrapy to version 0.18, the previous installed `scrapyd-0.17` was uninstalled by `apt-get`(Ubuntu 12.04) automatically. Is there a `scrapyd-0.18`? How to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapyd is now a [separate project](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.18/topics/scrapyd.html) as of 0.18.

It looks like right now they only have it hooked up to `aptitude`:

```
aptitude install scrapyd-0.18
```

[More here.](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

EDIT: well, I researched it myself:

```
ben@nixbox:~$ aptitude versions scrapyd
Package scrapyd-0.14:                   
p   0.14.4+1351083316                             <NULL>                    500 

Package scrapyd-0.15:
p   0.15.1-309-gc3e91ba+1350590037                <NULL>                    500 

Package scrapyd-0.16:
p   0.16.5+1375718980                             <NULL>                    500 

Package scrapyd-0.17:
p   0.17.1-22-gaa883be+1372791583                 <NULL>                    500
```

Sigh.  Their documentation strongly *implies* that you can find scrapyd-0.18 on aptitude, but as of this writing (8/11/2013) that is false.  I'll leave this answer up in case it saves anyone some time.

Edit2: well then, their [news page](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/news.html) on the documentation says **0.18.0 (unreleased)**.  [Github repo](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/master/scrapyd/VERSION) seems to confirm that.  So I'm afraid there's your answer for now.

Comment: Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "scrapyd-0.18"

Comment: @kev you need to add your associated repo to aptitude as they explain in the docs http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html

Comment: I've add `deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu precise main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @kev sigh, the `aptitude` was a lie.  I'll see if they have a tarball somewhere.

Comment: @kev sorry to be the bearer of bad news :/